# Modelling DB Structure - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, associations

I have a product model wherein the user can customise the product being selected. The user can actually customise the product on two fronts namely size and color. Size options as of now is currently of two types namely `size1` and `size2`. Color options are also similar to that of size where user can select between `Black` and `White` irrespective of frame size chosen for now. How can the variant data be modelled effectively in a rails environment? I am looking for the best solution keeping in mind the options for both size and color might grow in the near future. Please let me know what would be the best way to address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a class diagram which can help you understand how you should build relationship.

[image]

Size and Color will be `option_types`, `size1`, `size2`, `Black`, `White` etc will go into `option_values`

`variants` with `option_value_variants` will hold variants like Black Shirt of Size1

Comment: I went ahead with the above approach barring a small modification. I dint see any use for the `product_option_types` table in my scenario hence i skipped that table alone and implemented the rest of the schema as it is